# SyncVar not changing Bool on button press Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my first networking project. I tried to follow some tutorials and this is what I'm running into: I'm trying to simply change a boolean when a button is clicked. The button is in one scene and the text object down here is in another scene. So i'm running the same network manager in two separate scenes. I realize this isn't conventional but it has to be this way for my project. All I'm looking for right now is for it to change the text, once I understand how that happened, I'm sure I can figure out the rest.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class textChanger : NetworkBehaviour 
{
    Text text;

    [SyncVar]
    bool change = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if(change)
        {
            text.text = "it worked";
        }
    }


    [Command]
    public void CmdChangeText()
    {
        change = true;
    }

}
```

If I set "change" to true with a keypress, the code operates exactly as it should, the text changes. But it's not working when i click the button from the other scene. I'm using Networking Hud and the two scenes are in fact connected. But the variable is not updating.

[image]

[image]

In the first picture, the "Text" gameObject is running the "Text Changer" script. And in the second picture, the button has the generic "Game Object" object running it too. You can see it referenced in the buttons onClick area that's calling the "CmdChangeText" method on the "Text Changer" script.

So in my head, everything looks like it should be working, but it's not. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html):

> These variables will have their values sychronized **from the server to clients**

So if you try to set in on a client it won't work. It only can be done using a `[Command]` like you already did.

---

You should also check your console output. As far as I know In order to be able to call a `Command` method, the holding `NetworkIdentity` has to be set to `LocalPlayerAuthority`. I always had to put a special class for all commands on the `Player` object itself in order to make it work.

---

I know this is maybe not an answer but atleast a workaround:
Instead of waiting for the `[SyncVar]` you could just directly set the value using a [`[ClientRpc]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.ClientRpcAttribute.html):

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class textChanger : NetworkBehaviour {

    Text text;

    private bool change = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(change)
        {
            text.text = "it worked";
        }
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdChangeText()
    {
        // sets the value on the server
        change = true;

        RpcChangeText();
    }

    // This is executed on ALL clients
    // SyncVar is no longer needed
    [ClientRpc]
    private void RpcChangeText()
    {
        change = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol,  right,  so if I already did it and it's not working,  what else do I change?